# Prove an obvious property of intervals.

Tags: real-analysis

The converse may be easy to prove, but how do I show that if $[a_i, b_i]$ and $[a_j, b_j]$ are intervals of an ordered field such as $\mathbb{R}$ and $[a_i, b_i] \subseteq [a_j, b_j]$, then $a_i \geq a_j$ and $b_i \leq b_j$. This amounts to showing that if for all $x$, $a_i \leq x \leq b_i \Rightarrow a_j \leq x \leq b_j$, then $a_i \geq a_j$ and $b_i \leq b_j$. This seems confusingly subtle to prove, although it's usually taken for granted in theorems like the Nested Interval Property.

Comment: Well, if $[a_i,b_i]\subseteq[a_j,b_j]$ then in particular $a_i,b_i\in[a_j,b_j]$ and by definition of $[a_j,b_j]$ you have $a_j\leq a_i\leq b_j$ and $a_j\leq b_i\leq b_j$

Comment: Right. It's so obvious!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What can you conclude from $a_i$ being in [$a_i$,$b_i$]?

Comment: Well, I guess you meant $a_i\in [a_j,b_j]$ ?

Comment: No, I meant what I wrote, but as a hint, not as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, given $a_1,b_1\in \Bbb R$, the interval $[a_1,b_1]$ is
$$
[a_1,b_1]:=\{x\in \Bbb R : a_1\leq x\leq b_1\}.$$

If $[a_1,b_1]\subset [a_2,b_2]$, since
$$
[a_2,b_2]:=\{x\in \Bbb R : a_2\leq x\leq b_2\},$$
and $a_1 \in [a_2,b_2]$, then we conclude $a_2\leq a_1$. The same for the $b_k$'s with the reverse inequality.